# how to customize iphone keypad

Tags: iphone, keyboard

I want to add the dot and comma character on my main keypad. I do not want to switch to numpad everytime I need to use these characters. Is there any way to customize it?

I'm on iphone 13 pro with iOS 15.2.1

Comment: Look for a 3rd party keyboard app in the App Store.